# Algolia Tags vs Facets Use Cases

Tags: algolia

New to Algolia, and having a bit of trouble deciphering the difference (suggested use) of tags vs. facets -- they seem to be functionally equivalent.

The Algolia documentation gives one example of a tag with a user ID -- e.g. "user_1234", which could then be used for filtering.

However that seems functionally equivalent to simply having this in your JSON:

"user": "1234"

and then declaring "user" as a faceted field.

What's the difference / purpose?  Why have both tags and facets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're indeed correct that both can give you the same filtering functionality.
The main difference comes from facet counts that are computed at indexing time, which takes time.

That's why you can now add in your `attributesForFaceting` setting an `onlyFilter` modifier to your attribute, like so:

```coffee
{
  attributesForFaceting: [
    'onlyFilter(user)'
  ]
}
```

This will tell the engine that the `user` attribute should be considered as a tag or tag list (this syntax is currently undocumented, but should soon be).

The same logic can be applied to numeric attributes. By default, the Algolia engine creates data structures for all numbers indexed in order to quickly answer to queries like `nb_views>10000`.
This is also computation-heavy, which is why you can add the `equalOnly` modifier in the [numericAttributesToIndex](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-numericAttributesToIndex).